# Getting Images related to a tag from Instagram without user login

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm building a small web game which involves the player pulling down 6 public images from Instagram in relation to a tag.

I don't want the player to have to log into Instagram in order to play.

The Instagram API documentation seems to be leaning heavily towards a user log in.

I found an Instagram class on GitHub (linked below) which is the closest thing to what I'm looking for that I've found. However it is mostly for a user login, it does have bits for public access.

https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API

I've got the Instagram Object but I can't use it

I'm new to all API so the answer may be obvious.

Sites Pulling in Public images
http://searchinstagram.com/
http://london-now.jit.su/

Question ?
Could someone show me a way of pulling down images from Instagram related to a tag, using PHP?

Comment: Did you publish your game?

Answer (score 0):

I have a jQuery plugin - https://github.com/rickydazla/Hashtagagram

Answer (score 0):

I've found this url, not in Instagram's documentation, but it's very similar to the "oficial" url:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/edinburgh/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT_ID&callback=CALLBACK_URL,
where CLIENT_ID and CALLBACK_URL have been defined when you have created your aplication.